# How to change the database mode to STANDBY?

Tags: sql-server, recovery

1. I have a "log shipping" from server A(Database Name = main) to server B(Database Name = LS_main) .
2. I want to take a Snapshot Database From the secondary Database (Database Name = LS_main), but he id in STANDBY mode (Read_only) and I can't do it.

How can I do it ?

(I Thought that I can change the DatabaseLS_Main from Standby mode to bring it online, take the snapshot and bring it back to STANDBY mode...is it right to do ?)

Comment: You want to take copy of secondary database ?

Comment: Yes.... But I know that I can't do it in the standby mode, as a secondary database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Thought that I can change the DatabaseLS_Main from Standby mode to bring it online, take the snapshot and bring it back to STANDBY mode...is it right to do ?

What you are telling is [not possible using logshipping](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507022039/https://web.archive.org/web/20151010145752/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/reedme/archive/2009/04/24/log-shipping-database-snapshots-bummer-dude.aspx).

There are limitations of database snapshots:

> In a log shipping configuration, ***database snapshots can be created only on the primary database, not on a secondary database.*** If you switch roles between the primary server instance and a secondary server instance, you must drop all the database snapshots before you can set the primary database up as a secondary database.

There are some options:

- If your database is not that big, you can do a snapshot replication, if you **really** want a snapshot of your database as opposed to doing a backup/restore.
- If you want a near-to-realtime data on some secondary server, then [transactional replication](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/in-defense-of-transactional-replication-as-an-ha-technology/) would be a better option.
- Alternatively, you can use database mirroring. It allows database snapshot on the mirrored server but the [database must be in the synchronized mirroring state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).
- Now that SQL Server 2012 and 2014 are out with [AlwaysON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014), you can consider that as well if you want a read-only copy of your database.

*Note that database snapshots as well as AlwaysON are Enterprise features :-)*

Comment: How Can I Disconnect the Secondery Database from logshipping(then I can take a snapshot of him) and then Reconnect him to the Logshipping ?

Comment: Once you disconnect - meaning break logshipping, bring the secondary ONLINE and take a snapshot, you have to **reestablish** your logshipping again.